# iOS app doesn't handle "-[tag]" search URL correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app

A recent version of [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) handles some SE links in posts and show native UI instead of webview. This supports a search URL, but negative tag search URL makes wrong queries:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status-completed
  The app shows search result of `[bug][-status-completed]`.
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D
  The app shows search result of `[bug][-[status-completed]]`.

Of course, [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) handles both correctly.

Comment: Testing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift%20not%20ios?mode=all

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.5.5 or 1.6.0.

The app will be able to handle `foo+-bar`, `foo+[[[-[[[bar]]]]]]`, and `foo%20not%20bar`.

There are a still complex queries the app won't be able to handle, `[foo] or [baz] not [bar]` is currently treated as `([foo] or [baz]) and not [bar])` rather than `[foo] or ([baz] not [bar])`.  Similarly `[foo][baz] or [bar]` is treated as `[foo] or [baz] or [bar]`.  This is because the app doesn't yet support a complex tag query language.

Comment: Is there any beta builds including this fix?

Comment: @unarist Not yet.  I'm doing a *major* overhaul of the app architecture and haven't built out a beta since before I fixed this.